# Boto Autoscale in other region

Tags: boto, autoscaling

I'm trying to use autoscale module from boto. I reach to create an API connexion and get all groups in the default region(us-east-1).

```
 conn = AutoScaleConnection(ACCESS_KEY,SECRET_KEY)
 print conn.get_all_groups()
```

Now I need to create a connexion on the region eu-west-1, but I've always an error.

```
conn = AutoScaleConnection(ACCESS_KEY,SECRET_KEY)
autoscale = boto.ec2.autoscale.connect_to_region('eu-west-1')
```

Error:

> boto.exception.NoAuthHandlerFound: No handler was ready to authenticate. 1 handlers were checked. ['HmacAuthV4Handler'] Check your credentials

If I try with that:

```
autoscale = boto.ec2.autoscale.connect_to_region('eu-west-1',ACCESS_KEY,SECRET_KEY)
```

Error:

> TypeError: connect_to_region() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to pass additional parameters as keyword parameters, e.g.:

```
boto.ec2.autoscale.connect_to_region('us-west-2', aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY, aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY)
```

Alternatively, you could put your credentials in a boto config file (`~/.boto`) or in environment variables and boto will find them.

Comment: You're right! With the keyword parameters, it works.
Thanks for your help.